# Appending multiple tables in drupal 7 module

Tags: 7, hooks, updating

I am appending three new tables in my custom module using `hook_update`, but it is throwing below error when I try to run `update.php` file

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'schema_version' at row 206: UPDATE {system} SET schema_version=:db_update_placeholder_0 WHERE (name = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array ( [:db_update_placeholder_0] => 71000 [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => pemedia_library ) in drupal_set_installed_schema_version() (line 181 of H:\xampp\htdocs\brandenglish\trunk\includes\install.inc).
```

**Here is my code**

```
//my module install file
    <?php

    /**
     * @file
     * Install, update and uninstall functions for the pemedia_library module.
     * https://www.drupal.org/node/876250
     */
    /*
     * *Implementing hook schema
     */

    function pemedia_library_schema() {
        /*
         * Photographic page table 
         */
        $schema['pemedia_gallery_table'] = array(
            // Example (partial) specification for table "node".
            'description' => 'Table for storing information about image media.',
            'fields' => array(
                'imid' => array(
                    'type' => 'serial',
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'description' => 'Primary Key: Unique aggregator image ID.',
                ),
                'image_title' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'Title of the media.',
                ),
                'low_res_path' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'CDN url path for low resulution images.',
                ),
                'medium_res_path' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'CDN url path for medium resulution images.',
                ),
                'high_res_path' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'CDN url path for high resulution images.',
                ),
                'description' => array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'size' => 'big',
                    'description' => 'Description of the image',
                ),
                'bussiness_channel' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 60,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'Type of bussiness channel.',
                ),
                'user_right' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 60,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'Type of user right.',
                ),
                'geography' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 60,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'Geographic location.',
                ),
                'expiry_date_timestamp' => array(
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'not null' => FALSE,
                    'description' => 'Expiry date of image items, as a Unix timestamp.',
                ),
                'usages_restriction' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'information about usages restriction.',
                ),
                'owner' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'Information about the owner.',
                ),
                'copyright_information' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'Copyright information about the image.',
                ),
                'other_information' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'other information about the image.',
                ),
                'status' => array(
                    'description' => 'status field for the images',
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'length' => 1,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => 1,
                ),
            ),
            'primary key' => array('imid'),
        );

        /*
         * Illustration page table 
         */

        $schema['pemedia_illustration_table'] = array(
            // Example (partial) specification for table "node".
            'description' => 'Table for storing information about custom media.',
            'fields' => array(
                'mid' => array(
                    'type' => 'serial',
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'description' => 'Primary Key: Unique aggregator custom media ID.',
                ),
                'media_title' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'Title of the custom media.',
                ),
                'illustration_file_path_1' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'CDN url path for first illustration file.',
                ),
                'illustration_file_path_2' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'CDN url path for second illustration file.',
                ),
                'illustration_file_path_3' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'CDN url path for third illustration file..',
                ),
                'description' => array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'size' => 'big',
                    'description' => 'Description of the custom media',
                ),
                'bussiness_channel' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 60,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'Type of bussiness channel.',
                ),
                'user_right' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 60,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'Type of user right.',
                ),
                'owner' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'Information about the owner.',
                ),
                'file1_size' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'size of the file1.',
                ),
                'file2_size' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'size of the file2.',
                ),
                'file3_size' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'size of the file3.',
                ),
                'status' => array(
                    'description' => 'status field for the custom media',
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'length' => 1,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => 1,
                ),
            ),
            'primary key' => array('mid'),
        );

        /*
         * table schema for application page table 
         */
        $schema['pemedia_application_page_table'] = array(
            'description' => 'Table for storing information about static media asset of applicaton page .',
            'fields' => array(
                'appid' => array(
                    'type' => 'serial',
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'description' => 'Primary Key: Unique aggregator static media asset ID of application page .',
                ),
                'app_content_title' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'Title of the static media asset of applicaton page',
                ),
                'app_content_media_type' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => 'application',
                    'description' => 'Media Type for static media asset of applicaton page.',
                ),
                'status' => array(
                    'description' => 'status field for static media asset of applicaton page',
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'length' => 1,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => 1,
                ),
            ),
            'primary key' => array('appid'),
        );
        /*
         * table schema for product logos page table 
         */
        $schema['pemedia_product_logos_page_table'] = array(
            'description' => 'Table for storing information static media asset of product logos page .',
            'fields' => array(
                'plogosid' => array(
                    'type' => 'serial',
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'description' => 'Primary Key: Unique aggregator ID for  static media asset of product logos page .',
                ),
                'plogs_content_title' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'Title of the  static media asset of product logos page .',
                ),
                'plogs_media_type' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => 'product_logos',
                    'description' => 'Media Type for static media asset of product logos page .',
                ),
                'status' => array(
                    'description' => 'status field of static media asset of product logos page . ',
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'length' => 1,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => 1,
                ),
            ),
            'primary key' => array('plogosid'),
        );


        /*
         * Table for User content downloads
         */
        $schema['pemedia_user_content_table'] = array(
            'description' => 'Table for storing information about User content downlaods.',
            'fields' => array(
                'uid' => array(
                    'type' => 'serial',
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'description' => 'Primary Key: Unique aggregator ID for User content downlaods.',
                ),
                'content_id' => array(
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'size' => 'big',
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'Content Id of contents downloaded by user.',
                ),
                'content_media_type' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'Media Type of contents downloaded by user.',
                ),
                'status' => array(
                    'description' => 'status field of contents downloaded by user.',
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'length' => 1,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => 1,
                ),
            ),
            'primary key' => array('uid'),
        );
        return $schema;
    }

    /**
     * Create new database table for static contents {pemedia_application_page_table, pemedia_product_logos_page_table, pemedia_user_content_table}.
     */
    function pemedia_library_update_71001() {
        /*
         * Table for application page 
         */
        $table1 = array(
            'description' => 'Table for storing information about static media asset of applicaton page .',
            'fields' => array(
                'appid' => array(
                    'type' => 'serial',
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'description' => 'Primary Key: Unique aggregator static media asset ID of application page .',
                ),
                'app_content_title' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'Title of the static media asset of applicaton page',
                ),
                'app_content_media_type' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => 'application',
                    'description' => 'Media Type for static media asset of applicaton page.',
                ),
                'status' => array(
                    'description' => 'status field for static media asset of applicaton page',
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'length' => 1,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => 1,
                ),
            ),
            'primary key' => array('appid'),
        );

        /*
         * Table for product logos page 
         */
        $table2 = array(
            'description' => 'Table for storing information static media asset of product logos page .',
            'fields' => array(
                'plogosid' => array(
                    'type' => 'serial',
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'description' => 'Primary Key: Unique aggregator ID for  static media asset of product logos page .',
                ),
                'plogs_content_title' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'Title of the  static media asset of product logos page .',
                ),
                'plogs_media_type' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => 'product_logos',
                    'description' => 'Media Type for static media asset of product logos page .',
                ),
                'status' => array(
                    'description' => 'status field of static media asset of product logos page . ',
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'length' => 1,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => 1,
                ),
            ),
            'primary key' => array('plogosid'),
        );

        /*
         * Table for User content downloads
         */
        $table3 = array(
            'description' => 'Table for storing information about User content downlaods.',
            'fields' => array(
                'uid' => array(
                    'type' => 'serial',
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'description' => 'Primary Key: Unique aggregator ID for User content downlaods.',
                ),
                'content_id' => array(
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'size' => 'big',
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'Content Id of contents downloaded by user.',
                ),
                'content_media_type' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => '',
                    'description' => 'Media Type of contents downloaded by user.',
                ),
                'status' => array(
                    'description' => 'status field of contents downloaded by user.',
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'length' => 1,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => 1,
                ),
            ),
            'primary key' => array('uid'),
        );

        db_create_table('pemedia_application_page_table', $table1);
        db_create_table('pemedia_product_logos_page_table', $table2);
        db_create_table('pemedia_user_content_table', $table3);
    }
```

Can some one help please. Thanks

Comment: Table versions usually have a 4 digit number. Try 7101

Answer (score 1):

1. Change hook_update function name to `pemedia_library_update_7001` (remove first occurrence of `1`)
2. If you want to add tables with hook_update place it in `hook_schema`, than try like in example below. That is much cleaner way.

```
    function yourModule_update_7001() {
      $schema = module_invoke('yourModule', 'schema');
      db_create_table('table_name_1', $schema['table_name_1']);
      db_create_table('table_name_2', $schema['table_name_2']);
      db_create_table('table_name_3', $schema['table_name_3']);
    }
```

Comment: I had already run one update with name 7001 thats why I changed it to 70001 .... with one table above format worked perfectly .. but when I tried for multiple table it failed

Comment: If you already have _7001 than name next ones _7002, _7003, etc.
Your error is caused by too large update number. Field in DB can hold integers up to 32767.